# Discord.JS roleCreate event

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
client.on("roleCreate", role => {
  const channel = role.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "welcome");
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("DEFAULT")
    .setDescription(`A new role has been created\nPermissions List: ${role.permissions}`)
    channel.send(embed)
});
```

I am trying out different events from the Discord.JS Docs, however, when I came across the `roleCreate` event, I tried it out and when I create a new role, it works. But for the `role.permissions`; I am not quite sure why I'm getting `[object Object]`. How could I possibly fix this?

Discord.JS: `v12.2.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `role.permissions` is an object:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions

Use the `.toArray()` method combined with `join()`:

```js
client.on("roleCreate", role => {
  const channel = role.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "welcome");
  const perms = role.permissions.toArray().join("\n");
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("DEFAULT")
    .setDescription(`A new role has been created\nPermissions List:\n${perms}`)
    channel.send(embed)
});
```

To get it from `CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE` into `Create Instant Invite`

```js
const perms = role.permissions.toArray().map(e => {
   const words = e.split("_").map(x => x[0] + x.slice(1).toLowerCase());
   return words.join(" ");
}).join("\n");
```

Comment: Another question, so if I get `[object Object]` I should always use the `toArray()` method combined with `join()`?

Comment: No it's dependent on the situation, overall you should try to get the object somehow into a string, maybe a property, maybe a method, all depends.

Comment: It working now, however, everything is on Caps. One last question, how can I make it so instead of `CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE` it'll be `Create Instant Invite`? So far, I have this `if(role.permissions === "CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE") role.permissions("Create Instant Invite")` but it's still returning as all caps.

Comment: Firstly `role.permissions === "CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE"` will never work, look at the link I sent. It's an object so why compare it to a string? If you want to check if it has a certain permission use `role.permissions.has(permission_name)`, you probably shouldn't try to alter the syntax of the flags, if you want to display it in that format you will need to map over each. Edited my post to show how to formalize

Comment: The `_` between the permission names are now gone. However, all of the letters are still on caps. I tried changing `.toUpperCase` to `.toLowerCase` but the only letter size that changes is the front. So it's `cREATE iNSTANT iNVITE`

Comment: Yea I was thinking of another solution where it's all lower case, edited my post to match yours